# Easy proof for $\deg(fg)\geq\deg(f)+\deg(g)$ for arbitrary polynomials over an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am writing up model solutions for a second year algebra problem sheet at the moment.

> One of the problems is to show for polynomials $f,g\in R[X_i\mid i\in I]$, where $I$ is an arbitrary indexing set, that 
>   $$\deg(fg)\geq\deg(f)+\deg(g).$$
>   $R$ denotes an integral domain.

The degree of a polynomial $f\in  R[X_i\mid i\in I]$ is the maximum among the sums of the powers of the monomials of $f$. For example, for $I=\mathbb{N}$, the polynomial $X_1X_2^2X_5^3X_7 + X_1^6X_2 + 2X_2^2X_4 + 9$ has degree $7$.

A possible proof is the following:
Let $J=\left\{j_1,\ldots,j_k\right\}\subseteq I$ be the finite subset of $I$ such that $f$ and $g$ only have monomials consisting of products of variables $X_j$ where $j\in J$.

We only have to consider the monomials of highest degrees in $f$ and $g$. Express each of them in the form
$$cX_{j_1}^{s_1}\ldots X_{j_k}^{s_k}.$$

Now order them as terms of $f$ and $g$ in the lexicographical order according to their powers. E.g. the polynomial above would now become
$$X_1^6X_2 + X_1X_2^2X_5^3X_7  + 2X_2^2X_4 + 9$$
with $J=\left\{1,2,4,5,7\right\}$.

If $cX_{j_1}^{s_1}\ldots X_{j_k}^{s_k}$ is now the first monomial term of $f$ and $dX_{j_1}^{r_1}\ldots X_{j_k}^{r_k}$ is the first monomial term of $g$, then 
$$cdX_{j_1}^{s_1+r_1}\ldots X_{j_k}^{s_k+r_k}$$
is the first term of $fg$. Since $R$ is integral, $cd\neq0$. Since it is the product of the first monomials of $f$ and $g$ (with respect to the lexicographic order on their powers), it cannot be cancelled out by another monomial in $fg$. 
Hence, the degree of $fg$ is at least $$s_1+\cdots+s_k+r_1+\cdots+r_k=\deg(f)+\deg(g).$$

Now my question is if anyone knows a simpler proof. As far as I know, the students have not met the lexicographical order on cartesian products of ordered sets yet and therefore might struggle with this problem.

Is there a way without ordering the monomials with maximal power sum? I tried induction on both the length and the degree of $g$, but in either case I need to order the monomials again to obtain the result.

Comment: You can prove it for general graded integral domains. Moreover, if you translate it back into more elementary language, you can see that you needn't split terms of highest degree into monomials, but as a whole as a homogeneous polynomial.

Comment: So you mean that I can write $f$ as $p_m+\ldots+p_1$, where each $p_j$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $j$ (and $m$ is the degree of $f$)? Then my idea would be as follows: Write $g$ as $q_{\ell}+\ldots+p_1$. We now need to show that the homogeneous polynomial of highest degree of $fg$ is $p_mq_{\ell}$. But, again, I don't see how this can be done without considering its monomials, considering that we can only use basic arguments.

Comment: In your notation, $p_mq_l\neq0$, and you can estimate the degree's of remaining terms, and nothing is related to the lexicographical order here.